# Pandas Join/Merge Error: Can't join dataframes. Resulting Excel is blank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to merge two dataframes together.

This is my main dataframe which has a row of BillingPostalCodes

`print(df['BillingPostalCode'])`

[image]

In another table are Segments stored based on the BillingPostalCode.
`print(segment)`

[image]

If I merge both tables together to get the segment into my main table via

`df = pd.merge(df, segment, on='BillingPostalCode', how='left')`

the resulting column Segment in the exported .xlsx-file where the Segments should be displayed is blank.
Why is that?

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: What is the result of `df['BillingPostalCode'].isin(segment['BillingPostalCode']).sum()`?

Comment: I assume the data types of both columns don't match, `print(df.dtypes)` of both dataframes and post the output into your question, also you're overwriting your initial dataframe, you should assign the resulting dataframe to a new variable.

Answer (score -2):

Try to check indexes in both tables with .isin construction. Maybe, it is format problem. Try to reshape it to one format with lambda

```
df['BillingPostalCode'] = df['BillingPostalCode'].apply(lambda x: int(x))
segment['BillingPostalCode'] = segment['BillingPostalCode'].apply(lambda x: int(x))
```

Comment: no need for `apply` here just call  the `.astype` method. `df['BillingPostalCode'].astype(int)`, note if there are any `strings` in the column this will fail, so you should also note that, the solution to forcing a column into a given type is by using `pd.to_numeric` with the argument `errors = 'coerce'` which will default all non integers to a `NaN` value.